# Read/Write local json file in electron by angular

Tags: angular, electron

I want to create `get`, `post`, `put` of the function in electron to access the local JSON file.

1. Currently, I am using `json-server` to do this but I need to run the localhost every time separately before I run the electron project.
2. I used another library called - `electron-json-storage`. But I always get the fs error.

Is there any way to solve this problem or is there any other useful method to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`electron` uses `chromium` and runs on `node.js`, you can use `fs`(node.js buildin file system module) directly for operating local files.

For example, you can include `fs` module as a global variable on `window` at your `index.html`(from angular project)

```
window.fs = require('fs')
```

And build your file service for `get`, `post` and `post` functions or any others based on API from `fs` via `window.fs`.

reading local file for example:

```
@Injectable()
export class FileService {
  fs: any;
  constructor() {
    // or this.fs = <any>window.fs
    this.fs = (window as any).fs;
  }

  // read file synchronous
  getFile(path: string) {
    // return synchronous filestream
    return this.fs.readFileSync(path);
  }
}
```

Comment: do I include window.fs = require('fs') in script?

Comment: @Jim better to add this line to index.html for `fs` should be included first in order to use it in your service.

Comment: I tried to add window.fs = require('fs') in my index.html but I include this.fs = window.fs; in my constructor, it give me the error 'TS2339: Property 'fs' does not exist on type 'window'

Comment: @Jim did you create a **service class** and add **fs** to it? just follow my given example? Sorry, you have to cast `window` to **any** in order to access added `fs` property.

Comment: it is successfully to read the file but can it read as json format?

Comment: @Jim you can use `JSON.parse` to cast stream to object.

Comment: ok. I get the json file correctly. Thank you for your help and It is very useful answer

Comment: Can I check with you one more question? If I want to create a new data in json file. I should use writeFileSync right?

Comment: Where do I include 'window.fs = require('fs')', I did it in a scrypt in teh body but getting errors.